# How to choose what control to render at runtime in .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.5

it happened that I have to work with some old WebForms code, and it needs emergency refactoring.
I worked only with MVC before, so you understand me.

Lets imagine that I have a model:

```
public class Guy
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Personality;
}
```

And I need to display a list of Guys, I use binding:

```
<asp:ListView ID="GuysListView" runat="server" ItemType="Guy"SelectMethod="SeedGuys">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="Age" runat="server"  Text='<%# Item.Age%>' />
             <asp:Label ID="Name " runat="server"  Text='<%# Item.Name %>' />
             <Third control/>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

And lets imagine that Personality property could be like this

```
public class Logician: Personality
{
    public bool IsLogic(get; set;)
}
```

or

```
  public class Advanturer: Personality
  {
    public string SomeText(get; set;)
  }
```

So for my guy, if Personality property type is Logician I want third control to be a "asp:checkBox", if Advanturer I want to be it a "asp:TextBox". Also I want to have benefits of binding and etc.

My question is, what is a good way to implement such behavior, to render proper control based on model's property type? 
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Handle the GuysListView_ItemDataBound event.

In there apply your logic.

```
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var guy = e.Item.DataItem as Guy;

        if (guy.Personality is Logician)
        {
            e.Item.FindControl("checkBoxControlId").Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Item.FindControl("textBoxControlId").Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for comment.
So basicly you offer to place both checkbox and texbox for each Personality?
If I will have 10 items in list, I will have to add 20 controls and configure Visible property.
What if there would be 10 personality types, to place 100 controls for 10  List items seems ugly.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from adding the control dynamically when you're already in the itemdatabound event.  The more important point is that you will have to write some code instead of just configuring a template/view